# Функция, проверяющая простое ли число

Tags: c, функции

Необходимо проверить, является ли число простым используя функцию.
Решил вот так, но работает не до конца правильно. Не могу отловить причину...

```
int prime(unsigned int num {
    for ( int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++ ) {
        if ( num % i == 0 ) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: «работает не до конца правильно» следует понимать как «не компилируется»?

Comment: Если добавить пропущенную скобку, проблема будет в возможном переполнении при возведении в квадрат. Знаковое переполнение является undefined behaviour по стандарту.

Comment: раобтает она у вас правильно, только после unsigned int num вы забыли закрывающую круглую скобку. Ну и еще стоит отметить неоптимальность алгоритма. Но в целом верно

Comment: @DreamChild: А если `num == MAXINT`? Или простое число чуть меньше `MAXINT`?

Comment: @VladD я даже более того скажу - тут достаточно корня из MAXINT плюс один. Хотя, чего уж там - изначально возведение n в квадрат я не заметил.

Comment: @DreamChild , можно у Вас попросить подсказку как его оптимизировать? "тут достаточно корня из MAXINT плюс один" - это как я понимаю тоже через цикл? Извиняюсь если вопрос глупый :(

Comment: @Quaddro: Сильно оптимизировать не выйдет, надо менять алгоритм. (1) Популярный лёгкий метод — решето Эратосфена (легко гуглится), (2) для более продвинутых и более сложных методов смотрите [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) (нужно знание высшей математики).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool is_prime(unsigned p) {

    if ( p < 2 ) return false;
    if ( p == 2 ) return true;
    if ( p%2 == 0 ) return false;

    double limit = sqrt(p);

    for (unsigned i=3; i<=limit; i+=2) {
        if ( (p % i) == 0 ) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: У Вас маленькая ошибочка - 2-ка это тоже простое число.

Comment: Да, Вы правы

Comment: @nullptr, а Вы тестируете, что пишете?

--

Теперь поменяйте порядок первых if-ов.

2-ка  ведь четная и для нее сработает первый `if`, возвращающий `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая оптимизация. Сначала проверьте `num` на равно 2 (простое), меньше 2 и num четное число (не простые). Затем можно перебирать только нечетные:

```
uint32_t i, lim = sqrt(num) + 1;
for (i = 3; i < lim; i += 2)
  if (num % i == 0)
    return 0;

return 1;
```

Глянул асм. код. Несмотря на -O3 чуть лучше так:

```
 uint32_t i, lim = ((uint32_t)sqrt(num)) + 1;
```

--

[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), решето не для этой задачи. Решето - это поиск **всех** простых (задано их **количество**). Здесь же требуется проверить **только одно** число.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение на C++ хотите переписывайте на СИ источник: [решето Аткина](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using  namespace std;

bool is_prime(unsigned int num){ 
int limit = num;
int sqr_lim;
vector<bool> is_prime_f(num + 10);
int x2, y2;
int i, j;
int n;

// Инициализация решета
sqr_lim = (int)sqrt((long double)limit);
for (i = 0; i <= limit; i++) is_prime_f[i] = false;
is_prime_f[2] = true;
is_prime_f[3] = true;

// Предположительно простые - это целые с нечетным числом
// представлений в данных квадратных формах.
// x2 и y2 - это квадраты i и j (оптимизация).
x2 = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= sqr_lim; i++) {
    x2 += 2 * i - 1;
    y2 = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= sqr_lim; j++) {
        y2 += 2 * j - 1;

        n = 4 * x2 + y2;
        if ((n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5))
            is_prime_f[n] = !is_prime_f[n];

        // n = 3 * x2 + y2; 
        n -= x2; // Оптимизация
        if ((n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 7))
            is_prime_f[n] = !is_prime_f[n];

        // n = 3 * x2 - y2;
        n -= 2 * y2; // Оптимизация
        if ((i > j) && (n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 11))
            is_prime_f[n] = !is_prime_f[n];
    }
}

// Отсеиваем кратные квадратам простых чисел в интервале [5, sqrt(limit)].
// (основной этап не может их отсеять)
for (i = 5; i <= sqr_lim; i++) {
    if (is_prime_f[i]) {
        n = i * i;
        for (j = n; j <= limit; j += n) {
            is_prime_f[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

// Вывод списка простых чисел в консоль.
//printf("2, 3, 5");

if ((i == 2) || (i == 3) || (i == 5))
    return true;

for (i = 6; i <= limit; i++) {  // добавлена проверка делимости на 3 и 5. В оригинальной версии алгоритма потребности в ней нет.
    if ((is_prime_f[i]) && (i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 !=  0)){
       //printf(", %d", i);
             if (i == num)
                 return true;
    }
}

    return 0; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (is_prime(983)){
        cout << "prime" << endl;
    }   else {
        cout << "not prime" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @perfect, что произойдет если проверить число 4000000001?

Comment: у меня вывело что число 4000000001 - простое

Comment: Ради интереса посмотрел время этого алгоритма и простой проверки (как у @nullptr (Prime в выводе))

    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ -std=c++0x isprime.cpp -lm mtime.c
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 123456967
    123456967
    prime
    17412 msec
    Prime
    1 msec
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ 

Понятно, что миллиардный диапазон не запускал.

--

@perfect, очевидно, что если решать такую задачу (числа до 2^32) решетом, то надо **один** раз сделать решето с числами до 0xFFFF и многократно использовать его (т.е. если надо проверить на простоту не одно, а много чисел).

Comment: А теперь запускаем проверку на [WolframAlpha][1] и получаем, что 4000000001 = 47 * 127 * 670129, то есть нифига не простое.

  [1]: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4000000001

Comment: если так условие поставить то я с вами согласен, надо один раз сделать решето а потом многократно использовать, а код @nullptr вообще не работает.

Comment: @perfect, код @nullptr (естественно поправлен, как в моем комментарии к нему) как раз работает.

А вот Ваш код сообщает что число 4000000005 простое, что (даже без вольфрама) очевидно не так. (4000000005  прекрасно делится на 5).

Где-то у Вас для чисел больше 2^31 ошибочка закралась.

Comment: который раз уже влезаю с предложением реализовать хороший недетерминированный тест. Например Рабина-Миллера

Comment: @renegator, так напишите (например в "исследованиях").

@perfect, замените в программе все `int` на `unsigned int`. И проверяйте (если дождетесь...).

Comment: @avp тут даже не unsigned int, а unsigned long int надо, вот пытаюсь это побороть

Comment: когда выкрою время - обязательно напишу

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с renegator. Для VBA (возможно кому-то нужно) строковая функция, [возвращающая все квадраты простых чисел](http://orenstudent.ru/upragVBa.htm#primes)