# Как можно в двусвязном списке из входной последовательности удалить все числа, кроме простых

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как можно в двусвязном списке из входной последовательности удалить все числа, кроме простых?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, как определить, является ли число простым, или что-то другое?

Comment: Да, я спрашиваю как определить простое оно или нет

Comment: Например используя Решето Эратосфена

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функция, проверяющая простое ли число](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232452/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be)

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Comment: В бытность новичком я задал вопрос по регулярным выражениям, не имея о них представления (потребовалась практическая задача, решаемая ими). К счастью, меня не послали; вопрос не закрыли, а детально ответили на него. Благодаря этому понял, какие широкие возможности у регулярных выражений, прочитал 2 книги по ним, и теперь уже отвечаю, а не спрашиваю на ruSO по этой теме. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Одно дело - помочь человеку, который что-то делал сам (помогите - я и так вот:... и вот так вот:... и еще вот это пробовал:...), и совсем другое - полностью решать за кого-то ДЗ. Для этого есть сайты типа http://www.reshaem.net/ :) - плати деньги, и за тебя сделают все, вплоть до диплома...

Comment: @Harry, может, Marishca и не один час пробовала решить задание. Тут далеко не все новички сразу понимают, что нужно предъявлять в вопросе свои варианты решения. Притом в шаблоне закрытия ничего нет, что помогло бы им понять, как исправить вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: Не один день, я бы сказала. Нам ничего не обьясняли. дпли пачку лаю и все. Делайте что хотите. СТолько учебников уже перевернула.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Функция для определения, является ли число простым, может выглядеть следующим образом

```
bool is_prime( int value )
{
    bool prime = ( value == 2 ) || ( value > 2 && value % 2 );

    for ( int i = 3; prime && i <= value / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = value % i;
    }

    return prime;
}
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime( int value )
{
    bool prime = ( value == 2 ) || ( value > 2 && value % 2 );

    for ( int i = 3; prime && i <= value / i; i += 2 )
    {
        prime = value % i;
    }

    return prime;
}

int main() 
{
    const int N = 100;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( is_prime( i ) ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде просто но ошибок куча было.

Comment: @Marishca Не за что. Если помогло, то можете закрыть вопрос, выбрав, с вашей точки зрения лучший ответ.:)