# Проверить является ли число простым

Tags: c++

Я написал код который подставляет числа в формулу и собственно выводит числа,но мне надо ещё перепроверить является ли это число простым,что тут надо дописать?Помогите пожалуйста

```
for(int x=0; x<=28; x++){
    int number = 2 * pow(x, 2) + 29;
if( number % 2 != 0 && number %5 != 0){
    cout << number << "Число простое" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << number << "Число не простое" << endl;
}
```

Comment: ``````````%%``````````?

Comment: ошибся, там должно быть &&

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функция, проверяющая простое ли число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232452/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```cpp
bool is_prime(uint64_t number)
{
    if(number <= 1) return false;
    if(number == 2) return true;
    if(number % 2 == 0) return false;

    uint64_t limiter = std::sqrt(number) + 1;
    for (uint64_t i = 3; i < limiter; i+=2)
        if (number % i == 0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Если number равно, например, 101, то зачем проверять делимость на числа от 11 до 99?

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо. Исправил.

Comment: И в чем глубокий смысл `throw` в подобной функции?

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```c
 cout << "     ПРОВЕРКА ЧИСЛА НА ПРОСТОТУ.\n";
    int x, q;
    do
    {
        cout << "     Введите число > 1  : ";   
        cin >> x;
    }while (x <= 1);
        q = static_cast<int>(sqrt(x));
        for (int i = 2; i <= (q + 1); i++)
        {
            if (x % i == 0 && x != i)
            {
                cout << "     ЧИСЛО " << x << " делится на "<<i<<"  не является ПРОСТЫМ.\n";
                break;
            }
           if (i == q+1)  
            cout << "     ЧИСЛО " << x << "  - ПРОСТОЕ.\n";
            
        }
```

Comment: Бррррррррррр...